# Scrapy callback function

Tags: python, scrapy, yield-return

I have a basic scrapy script that's doing the following:

1. Visting a website
2. Using a rule to get all pages:

   ```
    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="pagination_top"]/a',)), callback="parse_page", follow= True),
            )
   ```
3. Within each page, getting all links to prod pages:

   ```
   def parse_page(self, response):
       for href in response.css("#prod_category > ul > li > a::attr('href')"):
           url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
           yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)
   ```
4. and visiting each of the product pages to get details about the product. I then get additional details from a different link

   ```
   def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        # select xpath here
        print '________________________BEGIN PRODUCT________________________'
        item = detailedItem()
        item['title'] = sites.xpath('//*[@id="product-name"]/text()').extract()

        # get url_2 from this page

        request = scrapy.Request(url_2, callback=self.parse_detailed_contents)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request
   ```
5. Finally here's the function that gets detailed information about the product

   > I think this last parse_detailed_contents is where I have an issue

   ```
   def parse_detailed_contents(self, response):
       item = response.meta['item']
       sel = Selector(response)
       sites = sel.xpath('//*[@id="prod-details"]')

       print '________________________GETTING DETAILS________________________'
       item['prod_details'] = sites.xpath('//*[@id="prod-details"]/div/text()').extract()

       return item
   ```

The problem is that my script returns item['prod_details'] for the first link but does not return any of the items for subsequent links.

> Is that because url_2 being passed in the same for all product?

Could someone please help. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you find any errors on console log while running the spider?

Comment: Thanks @jithin No errors... The script prints "BEGIN PRODUCT" for each product but prints "GETTING DETAILS" only for the first product.. All subsequent product pages only return "BEGIN PRODUCT'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding **dont_filter=True**

```
def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
 # select xpath here
 print '________________________BEGIN PRODUCT________________________'
 item = detailedItem()
 item['title'] = sites.xpath('//*[@id="product-name"]/text()').extract()

 # get url_2 from this page

 request = scrapy.Request(url_2, callback=self.parse_detailed_contents,dont_filter=True)
 request.meta['item'] = item
 yield request
```

Comment: Thanks so much @jithin THAT WORKED! I dont have enough pts to select your answer but I'll definitely be back once I have enough. Thanks again!